# Exact line Search in Steepest descent

Tags: optimization, algorithms, numerical-optimization

I wanted to clarify the idea of the exact line search in steepest descent method.

An exact line search involves starting with a relatively large step size ($\alpha$) for movement along the search direction $(d)$ and iteratively shrinking the step size until a decrease of the objective function is observed. Is this correct?
I.e. the only condition suppose to be satisfied is: $f(x_{k+1})<f(x_k)$, where $x_{k+1} = x_k + \alpha_kd_k$

In exact line search the step size $\alpha$ is not necessary to be fixed. Is this true?

If this is true then what is the difference of the exact line search from the backtracking line search? I know that backtracking line search is based on Armijo-Gooldstein condition or Wolfe's condition.

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this type of questions.

Comment: No. Exact line search is to find a local/global minimum in the search direction. It is basically only possible if the function is convex and differentiable.

Comment: No means that what I have written above are all wrong?

Comment: yes. You described armijo line search. (Not to confused with armijo Goldstein)

Comment: Ok so are two different things then.  What's the difference between those two?

Comment: one finds a minimum the other finds only a sufficiently large step with sufficiently large decrease

Comment: I couldn't find Armijo line search. I found backtracking line search (Armijo rule). Is that the same? If so, the backtracking line search says that you update your $\alpha$ in the algorithm if $f(x+ad)>f(x) + \sigma \alpha \bigtriangledown f(x)^Td$

Comment: yeah, it's a type of backtracking

Comment: OK. So there is a backtracking line search starts with some initial step size $\alpha_0$ and then gradually reduces it by the factor $\beta$ until the condition $f(x+ad)<f(x)$ is satisfied?

Comment: oh my bad Armijo is slightly different. That condition might be too weak to ensure convergence of the gradient method. I never encountered that condition

Comment: I know it's too weak. Did you see people use it before? (even if it is too weak).

Comment: like I said I have never seen it before.

Comment: Good! Thank you for your help